# Emacs Mac OSX after upgrade to 26.2 launches only in `-nw` mode

Tags: osx, start-up

I upgraded to Emacs 26.2 on my Mac OSX Sierra instance via "brew".

After the upgrade, the `emacs` command will not open a new "GUI window", i.e. it runs as if I passed the `-nw` args or ran it from an `ssh` session.

I.e. it does not seem to recognize the Mac windowing system:

This behavior has changed since yesterday.

**From the docs**
     Using Emacs with X
           Emacs has been tailored to work well with the X window system.  If you run Emacs from under X win-
           dows,  it  will create its own X window to display in.  You will probably want to start the editor
           as a background process so that you can continue using your original window.

How can I launch Emacs without it being in terminal (`nw`) mode?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the Homebrew version of Emacs and not the Apple provided version (22.1.1) at `/usr/bin/emacs`?

Comment: You may also want to look at the Homebrew cask, `emacs`.  This will give you a nicely "brewed" package from https://emacsformacosx.com/. Install it with `brew cask install emacs`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the Homebrew cask for Emacs. That will install a "brewed" package of Emacs from https://emacsformacosx.com/.

```
brew cask install emacs
```

The "regular" Homebrew package for Emacs is built without GUI support. Via `brew edit emacs`:

```
  def install
    args = %W[
      --disable-dependency-tracking
      --disable-silent-rules
      --enable-locallisppath=#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/share/emacs/site-lisp
      --infodir=#{info}/emacs
      --prefix=#{prefix}
      --with-gnutls
      --without-x
      --with-xml2
      --without-dbus
      --with-modules
      --without-ns
      --without-imagemagick
    ]
```

Note the flag `--without-ns`. This disables the GUI on macOS.

Comment: Woohoo! back in business! I do wonder "what changed" for me over the last day. Also, I lost my default font settings, but a small price to pay for "ctrl-k to the clipboard"

Comment: I had a similar problem, but brew claimed Emacs was already installed this way.  Reinstalling fixed it.  No idea why.  IIRC I could still get GUI emacs by launching from Spotlight, but not from Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, and tried the solution from @nega but it did not work for me. i am not a homebrew expert, but the command as listed didn't work and i had to use this syntax:

```
brew install --cask emacs
```

but like i said, the emacs window didn't open in X11.

i had success with the macports install instead of the homebrew install:

```
sudo port install emacs +x11
```

solution courtesy of @mariusm
[stackoverflow 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735651/how-to-run-emacs-in-ssh-x-from-linux-to-mac-os-x-with-xforwarding)